# MySQL multiple row literal select

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you define “literal” tables in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985295/can-you-define-literal-tables-in-sql)

Occasionally I find myself in a situation where I'd like to join an existing table to a table of values that are entered in the query. Something like:

```
SELECT ((1,2,3),(4,5,6));
```

Where the query would return two rows of 3 columns. Obviously this syntax is not correct, but it is possible to generate a single row of data in this way. For example:

```
SELECT 1,2,3;
```

Is there actually a way to do what I'm trying to achieve?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
SELECT 1,2,3
UNION ALL
SELECT 4,5,6;
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. I was hoping it would be more elegant but it works! I can use it combination with this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764881/mysql-getting-data-for-histogram-plot to generate histogram data without needing to create an extra table.

Comment: is there a way to name the columns in this, without specifying the same "AS column1"... in each line?

Comment: yes just give names to the first select : select 2 as id, 3 as code
union all
select 1, 4