# How to join table to value instead of another table in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

In SQL server we can update set join like this,

```
Update table1 set column = n.newvalue from table1 join (values('value1', 'value2')) N (oldvalue, newvalue) on table1.column = oldvalue
```

I try to write something like this is mySQL, different from SQL server mySQL use something like this

```
update table join table2 on table1.column = table2.column set table1.column = table2.column
```

So I tried to write it like this

```
update table1 join (values('value1','value2')) N (oldvalue, newvalue) on table.column = n.oldvalue
set table.column = n.newcolumn
```

but I always get the error check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VALUES, so is there something I can use other than values, or is there another method of writing this query

Comment: You will need a subquery with its own `SELECT` as shown in https://stackoverflow.com/a/985299/2055998

Answer (score 1):

MySQL does not support the table value constructor which is available in SQL Server.  The closest alternative, assuming you are using MySQL 8+, might be to use a CTE:

```
WITH N (oldvalue, newvalue) AS (
    SELECT 'value1', 'value2'
)

UPDATE table1 t1
INNER JOIN N n
    ON t1.column = n.oldvalue
SET
    t1.column = n.newcolumn;
```

This approach still requires an explicit reference to `SELECT` (table value constructor does not), but it at least lets you keep the literal value in a logically separate segment of code.

On earlier versions of MySQL, you would have to inline the above CTE as subquery, giving you:

```
UPDATE table1 t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT 'value1' AS oldvalue, 'value2' AS newvalue
) n
    ON t1.column = n.oldvalue
SET
    t1.column = n.newcolumn;
```

Comment: thanks for the feedback unfortunately i'm using mySql 5.7.28

Comment: @MisaelIndraWijaya Then you'll have to use a subquery...or maybe just create a table which contains these values.

Comment: i guess subquery is the only way to go, thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I'm wondering why you don't just write the query like this:

```
Update table1
    set column = 'value2'
    where column = 'value1';
```

This will work in any database.

Comment: well i want to update each different row, with specific value, so i don't think repeating update syntax would be very effective