# C# SQL Checking for records that should exist

Tags: c#, sql, linq, select

I have two tables, one the main entity and the other a translation record for it in a specific language

Recipe

- Id | unique identifier

RecipeTranslation

- Id | unique identifier
- RecipeId | unique identifier
- LanguageCode | string
- Name | String

Given an array of language codes, does anyone know how I would make a query, searching this translation table for any records that should exists (but don't).
There should be one record for each recipe & language code

The only parameter I would like to pass into the SELECT query would be an array of language codes

The pseudo code would be something like

- for each recipe
- check a translation record exists for each language code
- if it does not show me the recipe id and language code pair missing

This is my current solution

```cs
var result = from ingredient in _dbContext.Ingredients
             join translation in _dbContext.IngredientTranslations
               on new { IngredientId = ingredient.Id, LanguageCode = "uk" } equals new { translation.IngredientId, translation.LanguageCode }
               into ingredientTranslation
             from x in ingredientTranslation.DefaultIfEmpty()
             where x == null
             select new { IngredientId = ingredient.Id, LanguageCode = "uk" };
```

I am able to fetch per language code. so I am just looping through the language codes and running this to return me the records that do not exist

Comment: Where do the language codes come from? Another table?

Comment: They are a string array in c#, so I would like to pass them into this query. its the only piece of information I give it

Comment: Just thinking, is a good way to approach this, create a temp table with all the expected ids (recipe id and language code) then do a search on this recipe table to check if each exists, set a field like found 0/1.
then return back the not found result?

Comment: What are you trying to do with that?

Comment: given a list of strings (language codes) find the records that should exists in the recipe translations table, but don't
Then I can deal with them in code :)

Comment: Yes,  I was interested in that "deal with them" part. :)

Comment: o haha. any that don't exist I will then add a processed record for and insert it into the database

Comment: Well, ... you could do a temp table, left join and select where e.g. the Name column is null...

Answer (score 1):

This is easy to do in raw SQL with a left join and a [table-valued parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/table-valued-parameters).

You need to create a Table type in the database (once only)

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.Codes AS TABLE  
    ( Code nvarchar(50) )
```

Now, in your sql, you need a cross join and a left outer join. The cross join creates a line for every possible combination of recipe and required language code. The left outer join then brings in a translation *if there is one*. So if the language code of the translation is null, then there's no translation.

I'm going to tell you to use QueryFirst because it's by far the nicest way to [use TVPs from C#](https://queryfirst.net/authoring-sql.html#table-valued-parameters).  You can also [use dapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6232978/does-dapper-support-sql-2008-table-valued-parameters), or avoid the TVP altogether by constructing a [table literal directly in you sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985295/can-you-define-literal-tables-in-sql).

```
-- queryfirst
-- designTimeSection
declare @RequiredLanguageCodes Codes;
-- endDesignTimeSection

SELECT R.Id, RLC.Code
FROM Recipe R
cross join @RequiredLanguageCodes RLC
left outer join RecipeTranslations RT on R.Id = RT.RecipeId and RLC.Code = RT.LanguageCode
WHERE RT.LanguageCode is null
```

When you save that, you should see a generated execute method like the this...

```
public List<MyQfDto> Execute(IEnumerable<Codes> requiredLanguageCodes)
...

public class Codes{
    public System.String Code{get; set;}
}
```

Now you just feed the generated method a List of your desired language codes.

Answer (score 0):

If this is an ongoing need of your application, and you have a LanguageCode table, you could build a view, much like bbsimonbb outlined, called vwMissingTranslations.  Then you can query it in your code with an array of LanguageCodes in a Where clause.  This view could also be used for getting counts of all missing translations, or missing translations by Language, or by Recipe.